# adjancecy list, split an array and search a word in this array in c

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, strtok, doubly-linked-list

I open the input file. 
I read it, Store it in a 2D array, split into tokens.

first strtok for "\n" and store it
secondly strtok for ":" ignore it
and then strtok for "," and store it.

I want to search a word for every single line (which I stored it step 5)

For searching I use strstr but I can't do it.
I add my input file and code below:

```
int main (){
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen ("C:\\input.txt", "r");
 char *name[10][10];
 char row[100];
 char *token, *tkn, *tk;
 int h = 0, f = 0, l = 0;
 for (h = 0; h < 9; h++){
  for (f = 0; f < 9; f++)
    name[h][f] = NULL;
}
 while (fgets (row, sizeof (row), fp)){
  token = strtok (row, "\n");
  name[l][0] = strdup (token);
  //printf("%s",name[l][0]);
  tkn = strtok (token, ":");
  tk = strtok (tkn, ",");
  m[l][1] = strdup (tk);
  if (strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 1][0]) == 0
      || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 2][0]) == 0
      || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 3][0]) == 0)
    {

    }
     l++;
    }
   fclose (fp);}
```

I want to insert a linked list wth this function.

My input file :

```
George    :Math1,History2,Math2
ELizabeth :Math2,Germany1,spanish1
Adam      :Germany1,History2,Math1
```

I want to create a graph with lecture names and I want to use adjancecy list. For adjancecy list I need the connection of two lectures but I'm stuck with this step. How can I search whole line and then store an array. For example I search `Math1` . it is in 2 lines .And then I want to create an adj list `Math1 ->History2->Math2->Germany1` for `Math1` .Please help me

Comment: Can you explain what your code does at the moment?  And what it fails to do?  (ie How far you got with your code?  Are there errors?  What results do you get?)

Comment: @Grantly   I want to create an adjanecy list but I don't do it.  I had mistakes this part : if (strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 1][0]) == 0
      || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 2][0]) == 0
      || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 3][0]) == 0)

Comment: Your question is clear, but it will be hard for people to know which part you are struggling with...You do not need to give a long reply, but just a precise idea of why your code is failing.  Does it produce an error?  Or simply give the wrong result...What result do you want/expect from the IF statement you posted in your comment?

Comment: strstr will not return 0.  It will return NULL if it fails.

Comment: My expect is the code search for every lectures . If it sees in a row, its insert into list. For ex the code run for Math1 and then the output is Math1 ->History2->Math2->Germany1. But I can't do it.. obviously, I don2t know how can I do that ? @Grantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comments mainly, your `if` statement could be clearer if written like this

```
 if (!strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 1][0]) 
  || !strstr(name[l][1], name[l + 2][0]) 
  || !strstr(name[l][1], name[l + 3][0]))
{}
else
{
  InsertVertex{nodeHeader, studentName, courseName);
}
```

You will have to define and initialise nodeHeader, studentName and courseName

Use a debugger to confirm that your arrays are filled properly, and then follow through your code step by step  - and let us know how you go.

You really have far too many bugs to list them all...:Your l is going to cross your array boundary eventually, you are processing one line at a time, but hard coded 0 and 1 in your array indexes, and you may need to know the contents of all your lines before you start processing.

I would start by getting InsertVertex working with manually created data first, then add it into your loops and debug until you get it working with the file

Comment: Thanks, I change it like that. so, How can add to an insert lecturesif they are in same row ?

Comment: Do you have any idea for me?

Comment: Inserting lectures from the same row is easy, but I think you want to insert the lectures from a different row (adjacent rows).  Add your Insert code to the else statement, but you will also need to traverse your linked list to see if it already exists...Do simple steps at a time, simply add to your linked list first....(in the else statement that you need to add)

Comment: I want to insert lectures which connected to each other. So,do I  call insert function in else statement ?

Comment: I understand your objective.  It depends on your homework assignment whether you use InsertVertex or not, changes made to my answer above might be helpful

Comment: For example, can I store an array for all rows (in this input there are 3 rows ) and then I use strtok for spliting and then I call insertVertex function ?

Comment: is this a helpful for me ? what do you think ? you undersand my question please help me

Comment: Yes I think using strtok and strstr is fine.  I understand your question but cannot do all your homework for you.  Your name[10][10] will crash, if your names are more than 10 characters long. why is char name also a pointer to a 2D array?  Surely you want char name[10][300]  (300 gives a decent name length maximum).  You haven't really answered any comments/questions...Does your code crash?  Does any of it work yet?  Edit your Question with your improvements

Comment: Well, EDIT your question and put the run time error details in the question.  You will need to solve each error - one at a time.  You can't write the whole program in one step. You must break it up into small steps and make sure each step works.

Comment: @joseph - This is a really good exercise, and it is difficult.  Stick with it - but just get one thing working at a time.  Then slowly add more complexity...Otherwise you will get yourself in a pickle...Use printf to verify that your strings are correct, and fix errors and warnings as they appear

Comment: I find how can I use strstr and then now I want to insert after strstr . I have to work

Comment: I can't do it. do you have any source code for me ?